# mysqli_query with prepared statement in a class

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working with an old program which is using a `mysql_* functions` (deprecated) in a class for database connection and executing queries. Many pages are using this class, so I am thinking that I need to do some minor change to it. So I downloaded the program on my local machine and try to upgrade it to `mysqli_*` functions.

This is the class:

```
final class db{
static $db;

static function config($conf=false){
    self::$db = mysqli_connect($conf['host'], $conf['username'], $conf['password']);
    if (!self::$db) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_select_db(self::$db, $conf['database']);

}

static function query($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query(self::$db, $sql);
    if(!$result) trigger_error("MySQL UPDATE error: ".mysqli_error(self::$db).'<pre>'.$sql.'</pre><br>');
}

static function select($sql, $args=false){

    if($args['pager']){
        $limit = self::load_pager($args['pager']);
        $sql .= 'LIMIT '.$limit;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query(self::$db, $sql);
    if(!$result) trigger_error("MySQL SELECT error: ".mysqli_error()." using ".$sql);

    if(@$args['explain']==true) self::explain($sql);

    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $row[] = $r;
    }


    mysqli_free_result($result);

    @array_walk_recursive($row, 'de_clean_post_recursive');
    return @$row;
}

 }
```

I already changed them to `mysqli`.

Before, I am using this code to insert or update or delete the record to the database. Example of inserting:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transactions_in(
                    transact_in_date,
                    transact_in_total_sacks,
                    transact_in_from_location,
                    transact_in_to_location,
                    transact_in_note,
                    transact_in_by_user,
                    transact_in_date_added
                    )
                    VALUES(
                    '{$transact_date}',
                    '{$post['transact_total_sacks']}',
                    '{$post['transact_from_location']}',
                    '{$my_location}',
                    '{$post['transact_note']}',
                    '{$_SESSION['user_name']}',
                     NOW()
                    )";
    db::query($sql);
}
```

And now, I tried to use the msqli function with a prepared statement. Example:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions_in(
                    transact_in_date,
                    transact_in_total_sacks,
                    transact_in_from_location,
                    transact_in_to_location,
                    transact_in_note,
                    transact_in_by_user,
                    transact_in_date_added
                    )
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
    #echo $sql;
    #exit;
    db::query($sql,[ $transact_date, $post['transact_total_sacks'], $post['transact_from_location'], $my_location, $post['transact_note'], $_SESSION['user_name'] ]);
```

Questions:
Running the insert query with prepared statement gives me an error.

> Notice: MySQL UPDATE error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())' at line 10

Someone told me that `mysqli_query` does not run prepared statements. If that is true what is the right way to do it on my case?

Comment: _"Someone told me that mysqli_query does not run prepared statements"_ <- that would be correct. Please see http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 2):

your `query` method only get one argument. you pass two parameters to it:

```
db::query($sql,[$transact_date, $post['transact_total_sacks'], $post['transact_from_location'], $my_location, $post['transact_note'], $_SESSION['user_name']]);
```

by using `pdo` you more flexibility.

```
class db {
    static $pdo;
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$pdo = new PDO('CONNECTION STRING');
    }

    public static function query($query, $params){
        $stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($prarams);
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions_in(
                    transact_in_date,
                    transact_in_total_sacks,
                    transact_in_from_location,
                    transact_in_to_location,
                    transact_in_note,
                    transact_in_by_user,
                    transact_in_date_added
                    )
                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW())";
    #echo $sql;
    #exit;

db::query($sql, [
            $transact_date,
            $post['transact_total_sacks'],
            $post['transact_from_location'],
            $my_location,
            $post['transact_note'],
            $_SESSION['user_name']
        ]);
```

Comment: You cannot pass an array to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`. It's one of the major API design issues that makes PDO a superior choice.

Comment: @smoqadam, `db::query($sql,'ssssss',`  The 6 `s` here (without commas) are the format of the values to be inserted right? Which means string.

Comment: @Phil, Oops, you're right, I've never used mysqli before. I always rather `pdo` than `mysqli`. so I change the answer to pdo

Comment: @xkev yes it's correct, take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Any way using mysqli?